# Value from google-services.json is returned wrong

Tags: android, json, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

when i try to get the gcm_defaultSenderId for a specific android flavor at runtime it does not deliver the correct value.

For example: i got the flavor tst and the google-services.json looks like this

```html
 {
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "12345678910", 12345678910
    "project_id": "api-project-12345678910"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:12345678910:android:xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "do.something.app"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "XXXxxxx-XXXXxxxXXXXXxxxxXXXx"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

the json-file is placed in tst/google-services.json. When i try to access the gcm_defaultSenderId with R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId at runtime the returned value is : 9876543 . I expected the return value to be the project_number which is set at build to the gcm_defaultSenderId like its written here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin . Has anybody a idea why the value is not the same as in the google-service.json?

Comment: name of your build variant and the directory name should be an exact match

Comment: they are exact the same

Comment: http://imgur.com/AsjllwM do they look like this?

Comment: mind sharing your project structure? do u have a json file outside these directories as well??? make sure that there are no json files under app/src folder

Comment: the crazy thing is, i cant find the returned number 9876543 in the whole project. even i i search alle the files in the folder i cant find it...

Comment: i just learned that i can find the number in the build\intermediates files as SENDER_ID:9876543 . i still have no idea why the number shows up.

Comment: do you get the correct sender id for any of your variants?

Comment: No. They are all wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I tried to get the gcm_defaultSenderId like this:

```
R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId
```

The value there is a hex value like 0X23923912 which seems to me is a pointer to the correct value which is set at build time (?). Now it seems like Java is converting this value to a int (?) and returns the number 9876543. I fixed this by using the current Context:

```
context.getResources().getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId
```

Now the correct SenderId is returned.